# Setting up a second github repo for collaboration and pull finished code to main repo

Tags: git, github, collaboration

I'm planning to work with a few freelance developers and need to let them have access to my github 'real repo' to push commits. I'd like to keep what they do in a 'clone repo' completely separate from my 'real repo', and pull any finished work into my 'real repo' myself.

Do I clone the repo and add that 'clone repo's' remote to my 'real repo'? And then I can pull from it?

I'm not the most savvy git user quite yet so any detailed explanation would be even more appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fork your original repo and give access to the freelancers to the forked repo.

http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/

Once the changes are ready in the forked repo, pull requests can be sent to the original repo

http://help.github.com/pull-requests/

Comment: I was thinking that but when it's my own repo there's never a fork button. The fork button only appears on other people's repo. Do I just create a second account, or were you implying that I have the contributors fork the repo and pull from their fork? Thanks.

Comment: Ask the freelancers to fork the repo. That way, they can send pull requests whenever they are ready